# PyTorch model deployment in AI Platform

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I'm deploying a Pytorch model in Google Cloud AI Platform, I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: Model requires more memory than allowed. Please try to decrease the model size and re-deploy. If you continue to have error, please contact Cloud ML.
```

Configuration:

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['torch']

setup(
    name="iris-custom-model",
    version="0.1",
    scripts=["model.py"],
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES
)
```

Model version creation

```
MODEL_VERSION='v1'
RUNTIME_VERSION='1.15'
MODEL_CLASS='model.PyTorchIrisClassifier'

!gcloud beta ai-platform versions create {MODEL_VERSION} --model={MODEL_NAME} \
            --origin=gs://{BUCKET}/{GCS_MODEL_DIR} \
            --python-version=3.7 \
            --runtime-version={RUNTIME_VERSION} \
            --package-uris=gs://{BUCKET}/{GCS_PACKAGE_URI} \
            --prediction-class={MODEL_CLASS}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Pytorch compiled packages compatible with Cloud AI Platform Package information [here](http://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-ai-pytorch/readme.txt)

[This bucket](http://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-ai-pytorch/readme.txt) contains compiled packages for PyTorch that are compatible with Cloud AI Platform prediction. The files are mirrored from the official builds at https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch_stable.html

From documentation

> In order to deploy a PyTorch model on Cloud AI Platform Online
>   Predictions, you must add one of these packages to the packageURIs
>   field on the version you deploy. Pick the package matching your Python
>   and PyTorch version. The package names follow this template:
>
> Package name =
>   `torch-{TORCH_VERSION_NUMBER}-{PYTHON_VERSION}-linux_x86_64.whl` where
>   `PYTHON_VERSION` = cp35-cp35m for Python 3 with runtime versions <
>   1.15, cp37-cp37m for Python 3 with runtime versions >= 1.15
>
> For example, if I were to deploy a PyTorch model based on PyTorch
>   1.1.0 and Python 3, my gcloud command would look like:
>
> ```
> gcloud beta ai-platform versions create {VERSION_NAME} --model {MODEL_NAME} 
>  ...
> --package-uris=gs://{MY_PACKAGE_BUCKET}/my_package-0.1.tar.gz,gs://cloud->ai-pytorch/torch-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
> ```

In summary:

1) Remove `torch` from your `install_requires` dependencies in `setup.py`

2) Include `torch` package when creating your version model.

```
!gcloud beta ai-platform versions create {VERSION_NAME} --model {MODEL_NAME} \
 --origin=gs://{BUCKET}/{MODEL_DIR}/ \
 --python-version=3.7 \
 --runtime-version={RUNTIME_VERSION} \
 --package-uris=gs://{BUCKET}/{PACKAGES_DIR}/text_classification-0.1.tar.gz,gs://cloud-ai-pytorch/torch-1.3.1+cpu-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl \
 --prediction-class=model_prediction.CustomModelPrediction
```

Comment: Now AI Platform prediction supports custom containers. This should be the way to go now

Comment: ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Field: version.deployment_uri Error: The total size of files in gs://{bucket}/{folder_path}/ is 571419231 bytes, which exceeds the allowed maximum of 524288000 bytes.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: The total size of files in gs://{bucket}/{folder_path}/
      is 571419231 bytes, which exceeds the allowed maximum of 524288000 bytes.
    field: version.deployment_uri