# Can't seem to import my Pytorch model architecture class in my custom predictor class code for custom pipeline deployment on AI Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-training

I'm having problems deploying a simple Pytorch trained model on AI Platform Serving.

Here's the error:

```
Creating version (this might take a few minutes)......failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error:  "Failed to load model: Unexpected error when loading the model: Can't get attribute 'Net' 
on <module '__main__' from 'prediction_server_beta.py'> (Error code: 0)"
```

Here's the custom prediction class:

```
import os
import pickle 
import numpy as np 
import torch
from torch_model import *
class CustomModelPrediction(object):
    def __init__(self, model):
        self._model = model

    def predict(self, instances):
        input = torch.Tensor(instances)
        predictions = self._model(input)

        return predictions

    @classmethod
    def from_path(cls, model_dir):
        from torch_model import Net
        model = Net()
        model = torch.load(os.path.join(model_dir, 'pickle_saved_model.pkl'))
        #model.eval()
        return cls(model)
```

I've tried changing the code and saved model formats (.pkl, .pth, .pt), but nothing seems to be working. I've also tried including my model class in the same .py script as my custom predictor class, and that didn't work either. 
The pip-installable package contained all the necessary codes, i.e. the model code as well as the custom predictor code. 
Appreciate the help!

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60423140/pytorch-model-deployment-in-ai-platform