# Cannot deploy a small transformers model for prediction serving using Google Cloud AI Platform due to "Model requires more memory than allowed"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pytorch, google-cloud-ml, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I have a fine tuned `distilgpt2` model that I want to deploy using GCP ai-platform.

I've followed all the documentation for deploying a custom prediction routine on GCP but when creating the model I get the error:

> Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: Model requires more memory than allowed. Please try to decrease the model size and re-deploy.

Here is my `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="generator_package",
    version="0.2",
    include_package_data=True,
    scripts=["generator_class.py"],
    install_requires=['transformers==2.8.0']
)
```

I then create a model version using:

```
gcloud beta ai-platform versions create v1 --model my_model \
 --origin=gs://my_bucket/model/ \
 --python-version=3.7 \
 --runtime-version=2.3 \
 --package-uris=gs://my_bucket/packages/gpt2-0.1.tar.gz,gs://cloud-ai-pytorch/torch-1.3.1+cpu-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl \
 --prediction-class=model_prediction.CustomModelPrediction
```

Following this answer: [PyTorch model deployment in AI Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60423140/pytorch-model-deployment-in-ai-platform), I figured out how to get pytorch installed on my custom prediction routine, but am still getting the above error. I believe it may have something to do with the `transformers` package, as it has `torch` as a dependency. Can that be causing the issue?

I have tried every suggested route and cant get this to work and I'm still getting the above error. I'm using the smallest gpt2 model and am well within memory.

Can anyone who have successfully deployed to GCP please give some insight here.

**Update:**

So to address the above concern of `transformers` also trying to install `torch` and that may be causing the problem I rebuilt the `.whl` file from source with the additional packages removed, below is the edited `setup.py` file and built using `python setup.py bdist_wheel`.

I then added this `whl` to the required dependencies when creating a model version in GCP and removed the `transformers==2.8.0` from my own `setup.py`. But it is still giving the same error of model requires more memory =(

```
import shutil

from pathlib import Path



from setuptools import find_packages, setup





# Remove stale transformers.egg-info directory to avoid https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5466

stale_egg_info = Path(__file__).parent / "transformers.egg-info"

if stale_egg_info.exists():

    print(

        (

            "Warning: {} exists.\n\n"

            "If you recently updated transformers to 3.0 or later, this is expected,\n"

            "but it may prevent transformers from installing in editable mode.\n\n"

            "This directory is automatically generated by Python's packaging tools.\n"

            "I will remove it now.\n\n"

            "See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5466 for details.\n"

        ).format(stale_egg_info)

    )

    shutil.rmtree(stale_egg_info)





extras = {}



extras["mecab"] = ["mecab-python3"]

extras["sklearn"] = ["scikit-learn"]

# extras["tf"] = ["tensorflow"]

# extras["tf-cpu"] = ["tensorflow-cpu"]

# extras["torch"] = ["torch"]



extras["serving"] = ["pydantic", "uvicorn", "fastapi", "starlette"]

extras["all"] = extras["serving"] + ["tensorflow", "torch"]



extras["testing"] = ["pytest", "pytest-xdist"]

extras["docs"] = ["recommonmark", "sphinx", "sphinx-markdown-tables", "sphinx-rtd-theme"]

extras["quality"] = [

    "black",

    "isort",

    "flake8",

]

extras["dev"] = extras["testing"] + extras["quality"] + ["mecab-python3", "scikit-learn", "tensorflow", "torch"]



setup(

    name="transformers",

    version="2.8.0",

    author="Thomas Wolf, Lysandre Debut, Victor Sanh, Julien Chaumond, Sam Shleifer, Google AI Language Team Authors, Open AI team Authors, Facebook AI Authors, Carnegie Mellon University Authors",

    author_email="thomas@huggingface.co",

    description="State-of-the-art Natural Language Processing for TensorFlow 2.0 and PyTorch",

    long_description=open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8").read(),

    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",

    keywords="NLP deep learning transformer pytorch tensorflow BERT GPT GPT-2 google openai CMU",

    license="Apache",

    url="https://github.com/huggingface/transformers",

    package_dir={"": "src"},

    packages=find_packages("src"),

    install_requires=[

        "numpy",

        "tokenizers == 0.5.2",

        # dataclasses for Python versions that don't have it

        "dataclasses;python_version<'3.7'",

        # accessing files from S3 directly

        "boto3",

        # filesystem locks e.g. to prevent parallel downloads

        "filelock",

        # for downloading models over HTTPS

        "requests",

        # progress bars in model download and training scripts

        "tqdm >= 4.27",

        # for OpenAI GPT

        "regex != 2019.12.17",

        # for XLNet

        "sentencepiece",

        # for XLM

        "sacremoses",

    ],

    extras_require=extras,

    scripts=["transformers-cli"],

    python_requires=">=3.6.0",

    classifiers=[

        "Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable",

        "Intended Audience :: Developers",

        "Intended Audience :: Education",

        "Intended Audience :: Science/Research",

        "License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License",

        "Operating System :: OS Independent",

        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",

        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",

        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",

        "Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Artificial Intelligence",

    ],

)
```

Comment: I suggest that you create an issue on IssueTracker so the google engineers can give you some explanation about what is happening. You can create you issue through this link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=911831&template=1480251

Comment: I would suggest to deploy models on AI Platform Predictions using custom containers instead of custom prediction routines. Please look at this example to deploy PyTorch model on custom container > https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/getting-started-pytorch-container

Comment: Can you try using a machine with more memory as a test?